# Why some AWS IAM Policies cannot be attached to Roles or Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-policies, aws-roles

the reason why I'm asking the question is because, for example [this 'policy'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-managed-policy/latest/reference/AWSServiceRolePolicyForBackupReports.html) (AWSServiceRolePolicyForBackupReports) cannot be attached to any users or roles.
[image]

As you can see it clearly says:

> You cannot attach this policy to your users, groups, or roles.

This is just an example, but I'm quite sure that there are some many other ones.
Thank you.

Comment: Because AWS says so. What more do you need? They say this is for a service-linked role and you cannot use it otherwise, end of story.

Comment: You can always create your own "customer managed policies" that are specific to your use cases.